# EWS apis appointment class vs Graph Event class

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying migrating from EWS Apis to microsoft graph Apis and trying to refactor my code. Here is the my doubt:

In my application, All create/update/get meeting synchronization functionality is currently implemented using **`"microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Appointment"`** class but since Appointment class in graph is still in beta version that cannot be used in production.

So I have started implementing all the functionalities using **`"com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.Event"`** class.

I am not sure of the difference between the two and also unware of the impact it may have on my application.

A explanation about difference and impact would be very helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource in Graph is the equivalent of the Appointment item in EWS. There is no appointment resource in Graph. There is a [bookingAppointment](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/bookingappointment?view=graph-rest-beta) resource in beta, but that is specific to small businesses using a [booking service](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/booking-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta).

In short, you should be migrating your code to use the `event` resource.

Comment: Thanks @Jason Johnston for such quick response. You are awesome. Thank you.